# Symfony translation using csv file

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I want to make translations in symfony using CsvFileLoader.
I have written following code

```
    $file = __DIR__.'/file.csv';
    $translator = new Translator('fr', new MessageSelector());
    $translator->addLoader('csv', new CsvFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('csv', $file, 'fr');
    $translator->setFallbackLocales(array('en'));
    $translator->trans('Hello'));
```

But I am not able to get the translation for given input.

Comment: can you post the content of the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully run you code with the following csv file content:

```
"Hello";"Bonjour"
```

Take care of the default configuration of the [CsvFileLoader](https://github.com/symfony/translation/blob/master/Loader/CsvFileLoader.php#L23) class.

If you want to override you need to call the method [setCsvControl](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/CsvFileLoader.html#method_setCsvControl) passing various argument. From the API doc:

> ```
> setCsvControl(string $delimiter = ';', string $enclosure = '"', string $escape = '\\')
> ```
>
> Sets the delimiter, enclosure, and escape character for CSV.

Hope this help